# Silverlight, Expression Blend 4, using VisualStageGroup

Tags: silverlight-4.0, expression-blend-4

I have created a really simple silverlight application as follows:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:2"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Home"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="About">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="HomeLabel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutLabel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="HomeHide">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="9" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="113" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="AboutHide">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="112" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="HomeLabel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="AboutLabel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="110" Margin="104,0,163,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Fill="Gray"/>
        <sdk:Label x:Name="HomeLabel" Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <sdk:Label x:Name="AboutLabel" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Height="15" Content="About" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I have created a VisualStateGroup which contains 4 states, Home, HomeHide, About and AboutHide to show and hide a menu off the screen. But when i preview the states for About and AboutHide, the animation moves between the states using the Base state, then at the end of the animation is switches to the state i requested. To try and explain myself better, i was expecting:

About -> AboutHide

But instead i see:

About -> Base -> AboutHide

I'm missing something? Or using them in the wrong way and was hoping someone could give me some advice.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: See you have a CompositeTransform which seems to be used in Silverlight, not in WPF. Am I right?